# Inline::Perl5 not working with Lingua::En::Titlecase Perl module

Tags: raku

Got this:

```
use Lingua::En::Titlecase:from<Perl5>;

# this line is straight from doc
my $tc = Lingua::EN::Titlecase.new("CAN YOU FIX A TITLE?");
```

Get this:

```
Could not find symbol ''&Titlecase'' in ''GLOBAL::Lingua::EN''
```

As I recall, `Inline::Perl5` worked for me when I kicked its tires about a month ago. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. [Docs](https://github.com/niner/Inline-Perl5) didn't shed any light on things for me

Comment: *"Lingua::En::Titlecase"* Did you try with uppercase "EN" ? Try use `Lingua::EN::Titlecase`

Comment: There's Raku's `tclc` routine, in case you're interested: https://docs.raku.org/routine/tclc

Comment: Root cause of problem: Trying to program at 2am when you are so tired you can barely type.

Comment: Yeah, I fixed my tyop. Wasn't the OS. All is good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Could not find symbol ''&Titlecase'' in ''GLOBAL::Lingua::EN''

The reason for the error is that you used `Inline::Perl5` with perl module `Lingua::En::Titlecase` which does not exist. You need a captial "N" in "EN":

```
use Lingua::EN::Titlecase:from<Perl5>;
my $tc = Lingua::EN::Titlecase.new("CAN YOU FIX A TITLE?");
say $tc;
```

**Output**:

```
Can You Fix a Title?
```

Comment: Pro tip: Don't code at 2 am. Funny thing is, I remember looking to make sure I didn't make that mistake and missed it.